# Run Jupyter Lab notebook in another notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm sorry bothering you with a stupid question, but I'm facing the following issue with the %run command to run one notebook into another:

[image: %run command]

[image: The error message]

It seems to me it adds the .py extension and then it proceeds the research.
Thanks for your help!

I tried different method to import another notebook, but I'm kinda new to jupyter lab and can't get around it

Comment: Probably there is an issue with path or filename of  `classes.ipynb`. Try to check it in accordance with instructions in [Running Jupyter Notebooks](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/jupyter-notebooks/running-jupy-notebooks.html)

Comment: I exactly followed that guide but It seems to be working in it, while in mine apparently isn't. I can't see any difference though

Comment: What will happen if you put `classes.ipynb` into the same directory and run without path like that `%run classes.ipynb`?

Comment: It worked! do you have any idea how's that possible?

Comment: I was able to get your error. Absolute path to the file does not work for some reason but relative path works as expected. I do not know the relation of your working directories so try something similar to this: `%run ../Tesi/classes.ipynb` where `..` (2 dots) means to exit from current directory and go to the `Tesi` directory with the target file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run `classes.ipynb` from `current_notebook.ipynb`.

Possible solution is the following:

**Case 1: `current_notebook.ipynb` and `classes.ipynb` are in the same directory**

```
%run classes.ipynb
```

**Case 2: `current_notebook.ipynb` and `classes.ipynb` are in the different directories**

Note: Absolute path to the file does not work in this case for some reason but relative path works as expected.

For example the paths to the notebooks:

***root_folder > Sandy > current_notebook.ipynb***

***root_folder > Tesi > classes.ipynb***

```
%run ../Tesi/classes.ipynb
```

Note: The solution has tested on OS Widows 10, jupyter notebook, python 3

Comment: Hi, glad to hear :) and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).